# Input is disabled if space is pressed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a form, with command which works only if SPACE key is pressed, but in particular input text.
I want that a specific input will be disabled if the user presses on SPACE button inside the input. For example, if the user presses SPACE in `First Name` input, the input will be disabled.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, false);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.charCode == "32") {
        $("input#fn").prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

But it works if the user presses SPACE **anywhere** in the page. My meaning is, if he isn't in the input area and presses SPACE, the FN input is disabled.

I've tried to create a `input#fn` variable but I don't know how to use it as argument in a function.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the event handler to the input only, not the window:

```
document.getElementById('fn').addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, false);
```

Or jQuery:

```
$('#fn').keypress(checkKeyPressed);
```

You might prefer to make use of `this` in the function, instead of reselecting the input:

```
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.charCode == "32") {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        // or plain JS: this.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (if you use jQuery):

```
$('#user_login, #user_pass').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) == ' ') {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```